# Dynamically Keep Dropdownlist Same Size As Input Box

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, html.dropdownlistfor

I am working on an *ASP.NET, Bootstrap 3* website and have a problem with changing the size of the `dropdownlist`.

I can change it manually in the CSS to match the size of the other `input` boxes but I don't want to edit it manually every time I need to change it.

Is there a way to always keep the width the same between the `dropdownlist` and the other `input` boxes?

Here is what it is doing:
[iPhone 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIrYp.png) vs
[iPhone 5: Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J7tC.png). The problem is that the dropdownlist doesn't get resized within the div.

And here is an example of my code:

```
<section class="features">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "UsersAdmin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <!--ALL THESE INPUT BOXES ADJUST AUTOMATICALLY-->
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address, new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.City, new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--HERE IS THE DROPDOWLIST THAT NEEDS TO BE ADJUSTED DYNAMICALLY-->
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.State, new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-7 dropdownlist">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, Steel_Tech.STATE.States, "--Select a State--", new { @class = "dropdownlist" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Zip, new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Zip, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Zip, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Create" />
    </div>
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: what do you mean every time? It would help if you included some code with your question so we could see exactly what we are dealing with and maybe offer some explanation about what you mean "always keep the width"

Comment: We need more information. Could you create [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with the code rendered in the browser?

Comment: Ideally, the dropdownlist would behave exactly the same way as the other input boxes except that it has a dropdown list of course. I want it to always be the same size and change with the bootstrap classes like the input boxes.